# Change WPF textbox Text and keep undo stack

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, custom-controls, undo

I have a simple control, which base class is Textbox.
I want to change Text internally from that control (this.Text="old text + new text + old text"), but it clears ctrl+Z stack.
I have autosuggest popup and after inserting new value my ctrl+Z stack resets.

I have read that it sends *WM_SETTEXT* param, so after that ctrl+Z stack resets. The suggested solution is to select text and after that, change SelectedText value (it will send *EM_REPLACESEL* message). But in this case, the selection action also will be added to the stack. For Example if I my text is *Hello Wor*, and I am inserting World word from suggestion popup, then it will select *Wor* world and after that will set Selectedtext value to *World*. When I press ctrl+Z, I will see selected *Wor* word, and after clicking ctrl+Z one more time I will see correct result (without selection).

So I want to select text, change SelectedText and don't add this action to undo stack. Is it possible?

**standard method**

```
public void InsertSuggestion(string suggestion)
{
  this.Text = this.Text + suggestion;
}
```

**SelectedText method**

```
public void InsertSuggestion(string suggestion, int start, int length)
{
  this.Select(start,length);
  SelectedText =  suggestion;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. The Undo/Redo stack support is completely internal. You could have a look at the available internal methods with reflection, but you'd end up with a hack of a solution anyways.